# WKWebView and Dynamic Type + Custom Fonts

Tags: ios, css, wkwebview

I can't get a `WKWebView` working with both custom fonts and dynamic type at the same time, but it is working separately.

My CSS for this part is pretty simple:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

To allow dynamic type I change it to this:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
    font: -apple-system-body;
}
```

I have an observer to listen for the notification `UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification` to reload the webview, and it changes the font size gracefully, but with the system font, not the custom one.

Any idea on how to have both things working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally managed to solve it, just add this chunk to the CSS

```css
html {
    font: -apple-system-body;
}
```

And leave `body` like this, with no `font-size`:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
}
```

With just that, both things would work.

Comment: This only applies to the body text (which is good enough for the most part) but if you are modifying other parts relative to it such as header and it is set using `px` this does not work correctly

Answer (score -1):

The `font` [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) is overriding your `font-family` property, making only the system font applied to your selector.

You can't use two fonts at the same time for the same selector, but you could try using the system font as a fallback, like this:

```css
font-family: 'MyCustomFont', -apple-system-body;
```

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, though...

Comment: Thanks Torllsyn but it does not work. BTW, I managed to find the solution, I would share.